# Magento Shipping Estimator - Not Working (empty results)

Tags: magento

Not sure when it started happening, but I have a shipping estimator on the cart page that is not working. After filling in the info and clicking 'get quote', the page reloads but no shipping methods are displayed to the user... it's as if the form was submitted with blank values. The form points to:

```
checkout/cart/estimatePost
```

The contents of which are (in app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php):

```
    public function estimatePostAction()
{       
    $country    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country_id');
    $postcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_postcode');
    $city       = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_city');
    $regionId   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region_id');
    $region     = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

    $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
        ->setCountryId($country)
        ->setCity($city)
        ->setPostcode($postcode)
        ->setRegionId($regionId)
        ->setRegion($region)
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    $this->_getQuote()->save();
    $this->_goBack();
}
```

I added a Mage::log here to check the request:

```
$request = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
Mage::log($request, null, 'temp.log');
```

The array that gets logged is totally empty. No params are even getting here.

I've looked over the form itself and it is exactly the same as the form on the development site (which is working fine). So the problem is not with the form itself.

The only real logical conclusion is that another module is borking things up. I've checked through the different modules for overriding CartController.php, and while there are some that are doing so, none of them are messing with the estimatePostAction() method.

I'm a bit puzzled, any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

Holy smokes. The site owner must have changed something https: related on the server, because I changed the form's action from:

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost')
```

To:

```
$this->getUrl('checkout/cart/estimatePost', array('_secure'=>true))
```

And it now works.

Comment: You must mean you added `array('_secure' => true)` otherwise PHP would throw an `unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` error for `->` ;)

Comment: Shipping cost estimation working on cart page but not working on the checkout page, what is the error?